# passport-jwt: with every request must take unnecessary query to database or not

Tags: node.js, express, authentication

In paaport-jwt docs is coming:

```
passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done) {
User.findOne({id: jwt_payload.sub}, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
        return done(err, false);
    }
    if (user) {
        return done(null, user);
    } else {
        return done(null, false);
        // or you could create a new account
    }
});
```

}));

It means by every request from client we create a query to database To get user. (Low Performance. In session we haven't this) In the event that, when user authenticated, we set necessary information to payload of jwt (like UserID and User Role), and user in client can't change jwt.
I think that is not necessary.  
For what not use of this:

```
passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done) {
  return done(null, {id: jwt_payload.sub, role: jwt_payload.role});
}));
```

Does it have any reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the case where you have to have a tradeoff between security and performance. You are correct that first approach will create an extra query for the database but will be good from the security point of view. As you will not expose the user information on jwt in the first approach. You can use simple tools available in the market to [decode](https://jwt.io/) the jwt.

If you are not exposing sensitive user information, your second approach works fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot. for that we can use jwe or https (is that true?). I think if I must take a query to database with every request maybe session approach is better way vs jwt. what is your idea?

Comment: Yeah, using https will increase the security, defeating Man-in-the-middle attack. If you are only adding user `role` along with `id` then your second approach is good too.

Comment: If your express app is serving as backend for web application/websites then you can use whichever method you like. But if it's serving backend for a mobile app, I strongly suggest using jwt.